# How I can play an Amazon Prime Video movie with Dolby Digital Plus audio using Chrome browser in my PC?

Tags: audio, streaming, codec, webvideos, audio-quality

Currently my web browser Chrome (last version 80) cannot play Dolby Digital Plus audio. I know this audio is used in other devices like Apple TV, Roku, or Amazon Fire TV for example.

According to network tab of browser, just only AAC, 128 kbps, 2 channels.
Same with browser Edge.
Obviously Amazon prefers AAC audio since it consumes less bandwidth, but no comparisson of quality with E-AC-3 audio.

Then, how can I play in Dolby Digital Plus 5.1 surround sound in my web browser?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers do not include support for DD+. There is no way to play it.

Comment: Noted. Do you think it is possible to get any application where I can log in to Amazon and get support for DD+? I know it is not possible with Kodi app using suitable add-on.

Maybe setting up audio input and output of my audio target with kodi?

Comment: What do you mean by “log in and get support”

Comment: I mean I can sign/log in my account of Amazon Prime Video and app is able to play for DD+. Kodi app with suitable add-on is not possible. It is said "Dolby" when you select a movie but only AAC really.
Source of add-on: https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=349255

Comment: Kodi is just launching a chrome-less browser to play the video. There is no “app”. It’s the only way to play the video because of the DRM. And browsers don’t support DD+. So no, there is no way to use kodi to play DD+ for amazon video.

Comment: Yes, you are right. According to site https://developer.dolby.com : "browser does not yet support Dolby Digital Plus", which I guess it could be implemented next years maybe.

Comment: Very unlikely. DD+ is pretty old at this point. Opus is a better choice and supported by most browsers already. The only reason DD+ is still relevant is apple.

Comment: I disagree with you. According to Dolby.com: "Dolby Digital Plus is also a core format for Dolby Audio, built into Windows 10 and the new Microsoft Edge browser, available on PCs ...". Source https://www.dolby.com/us/en/technologies/dolby-digital-plus.html

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dolby-voice-13

This is an extension for chrome browser for running dolby atoms this works as expected, its free and can be downloaded from chrome wen store.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers DO support DD+ .. I dont know why this was innacurately reported... the New edge chrome and even the older legacy edge both than support for DD+ and edge chrome will also do atmos/DD+..  Now just because they support it doesnt nessarily mean that streaming services will Use it.. Netflix in the above mentioned browsers will indeed give 5.1 in both DD+ and DD+/atmos as I have verified it on my surround system..discrete channels...Now amazon however, will only do stereo through said browsers and even with the new win 10 prime video app, its still only stereo and no 4k support..... sad.